# awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: attempt to access field -1

Tags: bash, awk

I have a code sample that does not work at all. I permanently get an error produced by awk.

```
queried_num=$(echo -e "$domains"|awk '{print $(NF-1)}'|awk -F. '{print $(NF-2) "." $(NF-1)}'|wc -l)

queried_domain=$(echo -e "$domains"|awk '{print $(NF-1)}'|awk -F. '{print $(NF-2) "." $(NF-1)}'|uniq)
```

I don't really know what's going wrong and how to fix it.

The error is: awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: attempt to access field -1

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do??? Edit your question to include some concise, testable sample input and expected output and we can help you.

Comment: Hint: What is `NF-2` if your input doesn't have at least one `.` in a line? You probably want to qualify your `awk` code with something like `awk -F. 'NF > 2 { print ... }'`.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 scripts you posted:

```
queried_num=$(echo -e "$domains"|awk '{print $(NF-1)}'|awk -F. '{print $(NF-2) "." $(NF-1)}'|wc -l)

queried_domain=$(echo -e "$domains"|awk '{print $(NF-1)}'|awk -F. '{print $(NF-2) "." $(NF-1)}'|uniq)
```

could be written as just something like:

```
queried_num=$(echo -e "$domains"|wc -l)

queried_domain=$(echo -e "$domains"|awk '{n=split($(NF-1),f,/./); $0=f[n-2] "." f[n-1]} !seen[$0]++')
```

and then to discard empty lines (which would cause the problem you describe) would be:

```
queried_num=$(echo -e "$domains"|grep '.'|wc -l)

queried_domain=$(echo -e "$domains"|awk '!NF{next} {n=split($(NF-1),f,/./); $0=f[n-2] "." f[n-1]} !seen[$0]++')
```

If that's not what you're looking for then edit your question to include some concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.